# Is there a way to predict an PulseAudio Sink ID assignment?

Tags: audio, pulseaudio

When something like a browser opens a new tab, or any program requests an new `sink` from PulseAudio an ID is assigned (0..n).  If this happens in rapid succession (i.e. programmatically executing google-chrome) it can be tough to see what command specifically asked for it.  Is there a proven method for discovering the requestor?

Comment: Sinks are a PulseAudio concept. Try `pacmd list-xxx`.